# Understanding the proof: an odd map $f : S^1 → S^1$ induces an odd map $\pi_1(S^1)\to \pi_1(S^1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I had find a solution online. This is exactly lemma 3.8 on page 10 of this link:
http://www.math.ku.dk/~moller/f03/algtop/notes/covering.pdf

But there is a line remaining unclear:
[image]

It makes sense to me but I have not come up with an explicit deducement. Could someone please tell me how to reach this line by a step-by-step argument?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your quote misses a crucial quantifier.  Namely, the author says that *there exists* an odd integer $q$ such that this relation holds.  This is what it means for the original map to be *odd*.

Comment: Thanks. I know that the author means existence. I just wonder how can we get $\tilde{\omega(s)}$ is always such a number of this form from the fact that $f(-s)=-f(s)$.

Comment: I note that as $f$ is from $S^1$ to $S^1$, it is odd means that $f(-s)=f(s+1/2)=-f(s)$. But I still have not came up with a way to fill the gap between this and the equation mentioned above.

Comment: It is preferable to think of the circle as the unit interval $[0,1]$ with an identification.  Then being odd means that $f(s+1/2)=f(s)+1/2$ (care needs to be taken to account for the identification).

Comment: This makes sense. I see it. And now what I get is $p\tilde{\omega}(s+1/2)=p\tilde{\omega}(s)+1/2$. May I please ask how does this imply the statement of $\omega$ alone without the $p$?